# IIS servicehost with loadbalancing and custom config store?

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, c#-4.0, soa

Looking for some guidance on feasibility and implementation.. I would like to accomplish the following;
Create a custom ServiceHostFactory that can be used within IIS and Console/Service apps that scans a configuration for any registered services and loads them (I can do this via Unity) but also understands via the same config that a service may be hosted in multiple locations and does some load-balancing -- say round robin for simplicity -- on every call. Id also like this factory to (somehow) provide configuration data to the service, like a custom appsettings provider and allow those settings to change, additional service host locations for each service to be added/removed from load balancing, and other such management events. Ideally at runtime..

I believe this is possible, but not sure how? I've figured out the following;

1. Load service implementation dlls via Unity
2. Also host a 'config' service and create a custom settingsprovider that talks to this

   - how do I 'invalidate' a setting when it changes?

Still not sure how to implement round-robin and the eventing..

Any suggestions? Has this been done before? Are there samples available? MS StockTrader 5 seems to do something similar with azure, but i can't make heads or tails of the code and how it's all wired up..

UPDATE: In reading further, I think what Im after is a WCF routing service that can understand commands.. i.e. a routing service that i can send commands like 'add service' at runtime.. Still not really clear on whether this is possible?

Comment: As far as load balancing, why not use a load balancer for that?

Comment: I could, and currently do. But I'd like to load-balance per-service based on custom data. e.g. service A which is CPU-bound gets load-balanced based on the cpu perf counter, but service B which is RAM bound gets routed based on that.

Comment: Sounds complicated, and I wonder if that level of complexity is actually necessary.

Comment: We're planning to do dynamic scaling -- i.e. spin up new instances of specific services in multiple clouds (amazon, azure, etc) based on load. So the 'next step' is to have this same code that load-balances trigger spin-up/spin-down messages. Im basically trying to make our loadbalancing and scaling intelligent at a per-service layer without creating a separate site/project per wcf service.

Comment: All the WCF RoutingService does is provide a message routing capability and a very basic failover function. In reviewing the MS StockTrader app description, it looks like a better fit to what you're trying to accomplish. The StockTrader code is probably the best guide to the WCF learning curve you'll need to get past to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out ServiceRoutes in global.asax are close enough to fake this functionality. Added a serviceroute to a routing service and that's all it took.